# Is it possible to add a new line to a string from a remote server which is recognized by an app?

Tags: java, android, string

I am implementing a shop in my Android and iOS app. I have a backend server where I can enter product name, product price, product description, etc. That information is then stored in a database. I get a list of the products with all details via an API as json string. That means my Android app gets all the product details.

Now, I have something like this as product description:

```
Content:

1 bottle: red wine

1 pck cheese crackers with cheddar 75 g
```

Of course this is stored as a string in my description on the remote database.

```
Content: 1 bottle: red wine 1 pck cheese crackers with cheddar 75 g
```

My problem: How to add special character like new line to the string stored in the database and accessed by an API (json string) so my Android app recognizes it.

One solution would be to add some special string for new line like /addnewline\ and go by replaceAll() function and add then a new line to the string within Android, but that does not seem to be a good way of doing that. There must be another way.

```
Content:/addnewline\1 bottle: red wine 1/addnewline\1 pck cheese crackers with cheddar 75 g
```

Update: As recommended by some users \n does not work and is not recognized by Android when retrieving something like this from remote server:

```
Content:\n1 bottle: red wine 1\n1pck cheese crackers with cheddar 75 g
```

There seems to be no better way than my already suggested solution:

I will/have to go with replaceAll function:

```
//get description according to device language
item_description.setText(gift.getDescription().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n"));
```

Any idea?

Comment: That would be one way, and then there are probably countless others. Thus I think many people will consider your question "too broad".

Comment: It is a simple question. I doubt I am the only one storing product information on a remote server and retrieving the product details remotely within an Android app. So there is the problem with new line and special characters.

Comment: `\n` is a character that means *new line*. You may just add it to the database, and it should be recognized just fine

Comment: Nope: \n is not recognized by Android as new line when I get a string from remote server

Comment: then it is probably stored as `\\n`. which escapes the `\\` meaning special character. Double-check what exactly you receive from the server.

Comment: Tried \\n does not work.

Comment: when `\n` come as a string from server it will not be recognized like new line, the solution for you is use property for each item and then you will not have any problem. Example in you server build object like this :`{"name":"bottle", "amount":1, "description":"red wine"}` ,then in you android or ios app you will have POJO object with same property name and you will be able simple to convert json data to java or swift class .

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Or you directly store as html, or very reduced html containing formatting information. That is my point here. There are simply many ways to go about this, and to a great degree, the *ideal* solution depends on the exact requirements.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov I have something like that, but to have for every product detail an single object is not good as it must fit all products which I have and there is a box with diffrent produts inside. Sometimes 2, sometimes 5, but sold together within a box. And I want to write a story about the wine, where it comes from etc.but it differes from product to product. Description is one object for me.

Comment: Description is not an object it is property, you need to create one object that will fit for all cases. if you want to continue with your idea with one string you would have to parse your string and it is not the best idea. From my experience (and i have pretty much) i never saw server that response whole object as string without any separation, in most cases the data come in json or xml format. But it is your choice what to do i just say my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, property of an object, of course. It is like that: {"name":"BOX with Multiple Items you can't choose because it is already a gift box!", "amount":1, "price":19.99 USD "description":"1 red wine bottle, 2 cakes etc, 3 bla"}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add `"\n"` for new lines as you said.

If you want another way, use the text as HTML and add `<br/>`

I have the following `kotlin` extension for this:

```
fun html(str: String?): Spanned = Html.fromHtml(str)
```

Comment: I added \n as new line, but it is not recognized by Android as special chracter (new line) and is just shown in my textview exactly like it is stored in database: Content:\n1 bottle: red wine\n ....

Comment: note: your code is not `java` as stated in question tag

Comment: Make sure u have the textview supporting multiline 

textview.setSingleLine(false);
textview.setText("xxxx\n"+"yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an EditText with inputType="textMultiLine".

Comment: Nope, does not work. I go with replaceAll(), but thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't "\r\n" be used ?